# How large is Aragorn's Reunited Kingdom?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I'm trying to understand the scope of Aragorn's kingdom after the War of the Ring.

I understand that Arnor (the stuff West of the Misty Mountains and North of Gondor proper) was part of it; after all, becoming King of both was part of the bride-price for marrying Arwen, yes?

The part I'm not sure about is what happened East and South, specifically:

- What happened to South Gondor (now a debatable and desert land)
- Are Mordor and the freed slaves around Nurn part of the Kingdom?
- How far North/East into Rhovanion does the Kingdom control?  If it's anything  significant, the borders will look ... weird ... because Rohan is still independent.

Update:  Found this image [here](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Reunited_Kingdom) and am even more confused!

[image: aragorn's area]

- What is going on with the Enedwaithians; why aren't they part of the Kingdom?
- Whence the dotted lines on that map?

Comment: Who cares?  Ruling all those lands is for nothing until we get Númenor back.

Comment: @b_jonas who wants Numenor anymore ... if nothing else, it's at the bottom of the ocean.  I'd sooner have Rhun.  "Wain, women and song" for the win!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Aragorn reclaimed most of the land that previously belonged to Arnor and Gondor

Aragorn had reclaimed most of the land of Arnor and Gondor at the time of their greatest strength. Aragorn also gave land to the Beornings, the Druadan and peoples of Nurn.

> "The realm then extended north to [the Field of ] 1 Celebrant and the southern eaves of Mirkwood; west to the Greyflood; east to the inland Sea of Rhûn; south to the River Harnen, and thence along the coast to the peninsula and haven of Umbar. The Men of the Vales of Anduin acknowledged its authority; and the kings of the Harad did homage to Gondor, and their sons lived as hostages in the court of its King."

The semi-canon *Atlas of Middle-earth* also has a drawing and some details on the topic:

[image: Reunited Kingdom]

<sub>Will add more in a bit just need to finish my dinner</sub>

Comment: Is rivendell part of the new kingdom? Or did at this point all elves already leave?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam I believe Rivendell is in that weird white salient of non-kingdom area SE of the Shire, so looks like no.  Anyway, the elves all left during Aragorn's life.  From wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivendell#History ):  "It is not known when Rivendell was finally abandoned, but shortly before he died in F.A. 120 Aragorn said to Arwen that "none now walk" in the garden of Elrond."

Comment: Hmm, I guess you finished your dinner by now? ;D (Sorry, couldn't help but  write this ;)

Comment: @Mithoron Ask and you shall receive, once I’ve had breakfast ;) but yes I’ve starred the question (you’d be surprised how many times I’ve promised to come back). I’ll see if I can add some more details in ASAP

Answer (score 1):

The dotted lines show the extent of Gondor at the *end* of Aragorn's reign rather than the start, showing that Enedwaith, Rhovanion, South Gondor and Umbar were added to Gondor by Aragorn. And that should also answer your question about Enedwaith.